# Handling Multiple parameters in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a stored procedure which can filter data based on multiple parameters. Say there are 4 parameters(A,B,C & D). The user can select any number of them. Like they can select only A or A & C or all 4.

For example:

1. If the user selects only A, then it should be like:

   ```
   select Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5 
   from tbl1 
   where A = 123
   ```
2. If the user selects parameters B & D, then it should be like:

   ```
   select col1, col2, col3, col4, col5 
   from tbl1 
   where B = 'final' and D = '1'
   ```

How to write such a dynamic query with a where clause where the conditions change as per the selection?

Comment: Google `SQL Server catch all queries`.

Comment: How [A, B, C, D] parameters are related to the table if there are columns [Col1, Col2, Col3 and Col4]?

Comment: My advice would be, don't write a stored procedure that does significantly different queries based on parameters. The point of using a SP is to get the benefit of a cached query plan, but that will likely be bad in your scenario. Why not build your query in the calling code before sending the query to the server.

Comment: @Jodrell I would say that it's *one* point, not *the* point. There are other benefits as well.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I concede there are other benefits but, the idea that a Stored Procedure is a good place to dynamically generate a query is wrong. String building and manipulation are not a strength of TSQL.